# Python Pulp: Unexpected Results when Adding Constraint in For Loop

Tags: python, optimization, linear-programming, pulp

I am working in Python 3.11.1 specifying a linear optimization problem using Pulp. I am encountering unexpected results when attempting to add a number of constraints to the Lp problem in a for loop, however, I am receiving no error messages.

Here is the situation: I have a numeric value (the variable Freq below) and Lp variable names (Pos1 and Pos2) stored in a Pandas dataframe named df15 that looks like:

```
ID                Pos1            Pos2           Freq
28904502    id28904502_PosA                       1
28904503    id28904503_PosB                       2
28904521    id28904521_PosA    id28904521_PosB    1
28904596    id28904596_PosC                       1
```

The Lp variables have been previously specified. Their current status in the Lp problem (referred to as model1 in the code later on) is:

```
VARIABLES
0 <= id28904502_PosA <= 1 Integer
0 <= id28904503_PosB <= 1 Integer
0 <= id28904521_PosA <= 1 Integer
0 <= id28904521_PosB <= 1 Integer
0 <= id28904596_PosC <= 1 Integer
```

I need the constraints to be in general:

```
constraint_name: Freq + Pos1 + Pos2 <= maxPer
```

where the variable maxPer is specified outside of df15.

Furthermore, if Pos2 is empty, then the constraint should simplify to:

```
constraint_name: Freq + Pos1 <= maxPer
```

Therefore, for the 4 example rows in df15, I need the constraints to be:

```
limit_ID_28904502: 1 + id28904502_PosA <= 2

limit_ID_28904503: 2 + id28904503_PosB <= 2

limit_ID_28904521: 1 + id28904521_PosA + id28904521_PosB <= 2

limit_ID_28904596: 1 + id28904596_PosC <= 2
```

My code is:

```
maxPer = 2

for n in range(0,df15.shape[0]):
    model1.addConstraint(name=f'limit_ID_{df15.iloc[n,0]}', constraint=lpSum([df15.iloc[n, 3], df15.iloc[n,1], df15.iloc[n, 2]]) <= maxPer)
```

HOWEVER, this is what I am getting:

```
limit_ID_28904502: id28904502_PosA <= 0

limit_ID_28904503: id28904503_PosB <= 0

limit_ID_28904521: id28904521_PosA + id28904521_PosB <= 0

limit_ID_28904596: id28904596_PosC <= 0
```

df15.iloc[n, 3] is supposed to reference the nth value of the Freq variable in df15, but it is not showing up at all.

maxPer is not resolving to the desired value of 2.

Any assistance is appreciated.

## EDIT 1

This is AirSquid's answer code where I have added the maxPer and inequality sign. I do not understand  why the value of maxPer changes (It should be 2 for all iterations of the for loop. Instead, it is 0 for iter 1 and 1 and iter 2): That is one of the  two unexpected results from my original post. Also, the value of Freq has disappeared from the value of expr.

```
>>>
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import pulp
>>>
>>> maxPer = 2
>>>
>>> p1 = pulp.LpVariable('p1')
>>> p2 = pulp.LpVariable('p2')
>>> p3 = pulp.LpVariable('p3')
>>>
>>> data = {'ID': [22,45],
...         'Pos1': [p1, p2],
...         'Pos2': [p3, None],
...         'Freq': [2, 1]}
>>>
>>> df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data)[['ID', 'Pos1', 'Pos2', 'Freq']]
>>> print(df)
   ID Pos1  Pos2  Freq
0  22   p1    p3     2
1  45   p2  None     1
>>>
>>> for i in range(df.shape[0]):
...     expr = pulp.lpSum([df.iloc[i, 1], df.iloc[i, 2], df.iloc[i, 3]] ) <= maxPer
...     print(expr)
...
p1 + p3 <= 0
p2 <= 1
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cannot reproduce your problem.  (See below.)

My first suggestion is to move your data out of `pandas` and work with basic python types when using `pulp`.  It is usually easier, less error prone, and you don't need the bells & whistles of `pandas`.

```
import pandas as pd
import pulp

p1 = pulp.LpVariable('p1')
p2 = pulp.LpVariable('p2')
p3 = pulp.LpVariable('p3')

data = {'ID': [22,45],
        'Pos1': [p1, p2],
        'Pos2': [p3, None],
        'Freq': [2, 1]}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data)[['ID', 'Pos1', 'Pos2', 'Freq']]
print(df)

for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    expr = pulp.lpSum([df.iloc[i, 1], df.iloc[i, 2], df.iloc[i, 3]] )

    print(expr)
```

##### Output:

```
   ID Pos1  Pos2  Freq
0  22   p1    p3     2
1  45   p2  None     1

p1 + p3 + 2
p2 + 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. The inequality sign and the RHS value of maxPer is a critical component of each constraint. Please see EDIT 1 under my original post: I do not understand why the value of maxPer changes between iterations of the for loop.

Comment: The statements are mathematically equivalent.  `pulp` is just combining all of the constants (scalars) and moving the result to the RHS.  This is a more standardized expression.  For example in your second row:  `p2 + 1 <= 2` <==> `p2 <= 1`

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Never in a million years did I expect Pulp to do that on its own. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No worries.  Most of the frameworks for LP do this to put the set of equations into standardized format for solvers.